# Some isocline problem of ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y'=\frac{x}{y}$, then $c= \frac{x}{y}$ is an isocline.

It is transformed by 
$$y=-\frac{1}{c} x$$

Could I make c goes to infinity?

Comment: $\frac 1c$ is positive, why did you switch the sign?

Comment: Yes, you're right. My original problem is $y'= - \frac{x}{y}$ Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As $c$ goes to infinity, $y$ goes to zero, which means that the isocline with infinite slope will be the $y$ axis, this can also be seen by noticing that your differential equation is that for a hyperbola.

Comment: I'll check it later. Thanks to let me know your answer.